# Can two VBA Class properties write to each other to simulate overloading?

Tags: vba, class, overloading

Say I have a class called Vc that represents a geometric vector AB.
We can define a Vector either by two points (xA, yA, xB, yB) or by a point, a distance and an angle (xA, yA, Len, Angle).

I would like to write the class Vc such that its properties can both be optional (to accommodate the above two methods of definition) and be performing automatically the calculation needed to "fill the missing optional
data": that is if the user writes to the properties xA, yA, xB, yB, then
the missing properties Len and Angle be automatically calculated by the code,
and vice versa.

Now to simply the coding, I will treat a similar problem instead of the 
geometric problem:

suppose i have two numbers NbA and NbB, with NbA = 2 NbB, and the user can enter either NbA or NbB,

I tried this code, hoping that at least NbB be calculated by NbA
(or entered by the user)

```
Private pNbA As Double
Private pNbB As Double

Public Property Get NbA() As Double
 NbA = pNbA
End Property

Public Property Let NbA(value As Double)
 pNbA = value
End Property

Public Property Get NbB() As Double
 NbB = pNbB
End Property

Public Property Let NbB(NbA As Double)
 pNbB = NbA * 2
End Property
```

But when testing I got NbB = 0 (while nbA=1):

```
Sub TestAbove()
 Dim aTest As TestClass
 Set aTest = New TestClass
 aTest.nbA = 1
 MsgBox aTest.nbB 'this gives 0
End Sub
```

I hope that i can solve this issue within the properties 
part itself of the class, without resorting to writing a lot
of methods that would introduce duplication of definitions,
I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.NET you would use a `Nullable(Of Double)`.
In VBA for the same purpose you can use `Variant/Empty`:

```
Private pNbA As Variant  ' Empty by default

Public Property Get NbA() As Double
  if IsEmpty(pNbA) then NbA = 2 * NbB else NbA = pNbA
End Property

Public Property Let NbA(value As Double)
  pNbA = value
End Property
```

However I believe it would be better if you defined class properties in a way that they only return stored values and do not depend on each other, and create several constructor functions in a module that would accept your different sets of arguments and initialize all fields of the class properly as if all properties were supplied.

Comment: And if write a symetric portion for NbB, then at run time I can either exploit this relation or that, but not both... as I tried now.

Comment: @ZiadElHachem If both values are empty you don't have anything to return anyway. That is why I'm advising you go with the constructor approach where you properly calculate all values beforehand based on the user input.

Comment: And by saying 'constructor functions': you mean regular functions in a regular module, that would calculate NbA and NbB and supply both to the class, wright?

Comment: @ZiadElHachem Yes, and that is only because VBA does not support parametrized constructors. E.g. you could have `Function VectorFromPoints(xA, yA, xB, yB) As Vc` and `Function VectorFromAngle(xA, yA, Len, Angle) As Vc`.

Comment: Many Thanks GSerg. That was really helpful